# How to reloadData for tableview after data been prepared in a asynchronously method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I use `URLSession` to get data from a resource API for tableview'data. So I need to `reloadData()` after data prepared by the URLSession task. But this will lead to,

> UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only

And when I run the app, at begin the tableview is blank. Only after I croll the screen the data will show. But if not call `reloadData()` in the URLSession task, the screen is blank all the way.

```
func getData() {
    let dataUrl = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/app/?json=1")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dataUrl! as URL) {data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            self.data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never access any UI from background threads, you must do it from the main thread, to do this you may use gcd:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

While accessing UI (read everything UIKit) from background thread may work sometimes, you'll end up with bugs including crashes, blown up display or gazenbugs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do any UI update operation in background thread. So can put it in main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you try to perform UI operation in background thread it will cause crash.

Answer (score 2):

#### The best way to Update UI Views .. Use main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
  yourTableView.reloadData()
})
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
func getData() {
let dataUrl = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/app/?json=1")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: dataUrl! as URL) {data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    do {
        self.data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        }

    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
}
```